# iSCSI support in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, iscsi

Does Windows Server 2008 support iSCSI? If yes, how to configure Windows Server 2008 to connect to an iSCSI disk? Does Windows Server 2008 supports all kinds/models of iSCSI or some specific kinds/models of iSCSI?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. iSCSI is a standard, so there's no real limitation on any brand that it will or won't support. If it's iSCSI, most likely you can use it. Keep in mind that there is a good bit of difference in configuration between brands - I've found EMC, for example, to be very easy to configure (though it does require a piece of software be installed on the OS). LeftHand is a bit more tedious, but it will work with the Microsoft iSCSI Initiator without additional software. (The EMC software is what makes it easy).

You'll find the iSCSI initiator under Administrative Tools. You'll probably need the WWN in order to add the server to the iSCSI permissions on whatever SAN you are using, so that's about as far as I can go without knowing additional details.

Comment: Thanks Jes, is there a general guide about how to configure iSCSI from Windows Server 2008? I am not sure whether from Windows Server 2008, configuring connection to iSCSI disk is general (I mean common to all vendors), or not general (different vendor has different configuration steps)? Could you show me some related configuration steps? For example, it is appreciate if you could provide me some document about how to connect to EMC devide and connect to LeftHand device?

Comment: I can, this is a very long answer though. I would recommend you start here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee338476(WS.10).aspx. This is a good Technet guide all about iSCSI. You are welcome to contact me directly for additional questions.

Comment: Thanks Jes! You mentioned for EMC, we need to install additional software, and for LeftHand, we could directly configure through Microsoft iSCSI Initiator without additional software. Do you have related document from EMC and LeftHand to prove what you mentioned above? :-)

Comment: (continued) I want to learn how different vendor products are using different configuration steps.

Comment: EMC's documentation is available from their support site (http://www.emc.com/microsites/clariion-support/pdf/300-003-805.pdf) site, Jes linked to the definitive Microsoft document. Equallogic (Dell) can work with the MS initiator alone but benefits significantly from a Dell installable module that enhances multi-pathing\load balancing ( http://www.equallogic.com/resourcecenter/assetview.aspx?id=5255 ) .

Comment: Just to add - I'm not certain where the documentation is (I'll have to dig), I can tell you from personal experience though - we have both LeftHand and EMC in house, that's how I know the configuration differences. However, our LeftHands are getting old, it's possible things have changed now that they are owned by HP...